# Android unable to empty listview items

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to prevent my listview items to append when i press the button twice. I tried to use .Clear() but I dont know where to put it or how to put it, sometimes it stops items from even populating or doesn't clear the items at all.

global stuffs:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
ArrayList<MessageDetails> details;
```

My button:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                //Tried clearing adapter first before code runs but items do not even get displayed
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //sendPostData calls refreshListView method
                new sendPostData().execute(nric.getText().toString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

my refreshListView() method:

```
private void refreshListView()
{       
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    myInfoList.setAdapter(adapter);

    details = new ArrayList<MessageDetails>();
    MessageDetails Detail;

    Detail = new MessageDetails();

    for (int i =0; i < itemName.size(); i++)
    {
        float totalprice = itemPrice.get(i) * Quantity.get(i);
        Detail = new MessageDetails();
        Detail.setitemName(itemName.get(i));
        Detail.setItemDescription(description.get(i));
        Detail.setitemPrice(String.valueOf(totalprice));
        Detail.setQuantity(Quantity.get(i).toString() + " sets");
        Detail.setDate(purchaseDate.get(i).toString());
        details.add(Detail);
    }   

    myInfoList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(details , getActivity()));
}
```

*EDIT* removed first adapter.

Global item:

```
CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;
```

refreshListView:

```
private void refreshListView()
{           
    details = new ArrayList<MessageDetails>();
    MessageDetails Detail;

    Detail = new MessageDetails();

    for (int i =0; i < itemName.size(); i++)
    {
        float totalprice = itemPrice.get(i) * Quantity.get(i);
        Detail = new MessageDetails();
        Detail.setitemName(itemName.get(i));
        Detail.setItemDescription(description.get(i));
        Detail.setitemPrice(String.valueOf(totalprice));
        Detail.setQuantity(Quantity.get(i).toString() + " sets");
        Detail.setDate(purchaseDate.get(i).toString());
        details.add(Detail);
    }   

    mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(details , getActivity());
    myInfoList.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
}
```

Comment: refreshListView() is in aync task -sendPostData()??

Comment: yes, with other codes but it do not affect the adapter

Answer (score 0):

you submit two differnts `Adapter` instance to your `ListView`, and the latter override the former instance. So you should keep a reference to `CustomAdapter` and write a method do clear the dataset.

```
CustomAdapter mCustomAdpater = new CustomAdapter(details , getActivity()); 
myInfoList.setAdapter(mCustomAdpater);
```

inside CustomAdapter, write your own `clear()` method and, inside `onClick()` you will call

```
mCustomAdpater.clear();
```

Comment: do you see items from both the adpater?

Comment: hmm, removed first adapter.. but mCustomAdapter doesn't have .clear

Comment: didi you wrote CustomAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        listview.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        listview.removeAllViewsFromAdapter();
        listview.setAdapter(null);
        listview.refreshDrawableState();
        listview.removeViews(0, listview.getChildCount());
```